# Change the height of a relative layout multiple times

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to change the height of a relative layout that contains a listview. It works fine the first time I call it, but if i call the same code again later to change the height to a different value it does nothing. Why is this and how do I make it work?

```
LayoutParams params = myrelativelayout.getLayoutParams(); 
params.height = newHeight;
```

Comment: Ya it won't as when you the view's layout params again, it will return the original height. Try setLayoutParams(params)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add myrelativelayout.setLayoutParams(params); every time you change it. This will make sure the view is invalidated each time and that you update the Actual params object for the view.

Comment: So that would be?: `LayoutParams params = myrelativelayout.getLayoutParams(); 
params.height = 150;
    myrelativelayout.setLayoutParams(params);`